# How to declare Stored procedure with Table-valued parameter in PowerBuilder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, powerbuilder

I made a TVP stored procedure in MS SQL Server 2008:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [TVPSP] @CID INT
    ,@OID INT = NULL
    ,@GAS ParamTypeTVP readonly
    ,@ErrorText VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    select 1

    RETURN
END
```

I have also created a TVP Type:

```
CREATE TYPE [MDF].[ParamTypeTVP] AS TABLE(
    [ParamID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pInt1] [int] NULL,
    [pVarchar1] [varchar](777) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ParamID] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
```

I generated the declaration with the Powerbuilder built-in method, the result is:

```
function long TVPSP(long CID,long OID,string GAS,ref string ErrorText) RPCFUNC ALIAS FOR "TVPSP"
```

So as you see the PB generated a string variable for the TVP parameter which is false (and of course the call fails from PB).
Is it possible to make it work somehow? Of course I have ideas for workarounds (for example making a wrapper sp to ignore the TVP parameters), but I would like to know how to make it work in this way with TVP!

Thx in advance!

Gábor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news, it may not be supported based on this from the PB12.5 documentation:

> Unsupported SQL Server 2008 features
>
> The PowerBuilder SNC interface does not support the User-Defined Table
>   Type (a user-defined type that represents the definition of a table
>   structure) that was introduced in SQL Server 2008.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.help.pb.12.5/title.htm

IF you wanted to keep trying (if there is a will there is a way) then try using data type of "any" instead of string, or try making a structure that matches the table and pass an array of your structure as parameter instead of the string.